# Text composition based on categorical features

Tags: machine-learning, python, text-mining

The problem I have to solve is to find a model that links categorical features (bool type actually) to text documents.

The categorical features are answers to questions. Any different combination of answers leads to a different text document. So, the training dataset should be a pandas dataframe in which the features are booleans and the target variable is text (it could be a very long string or the list of lines in the doc). The target text is built arranging chunks of pre-defined text. Therefore, the goal of the model is to predict text documents associated to features patterns not included in the training set.

I did not faced similar kind of problems before. It is not a matter of categorizing text, it is more close to a regression problem, since the target variable is different for every different pattern of features.

Any help? Thank you in advance!
Alessio

Comment: Could you make the question more precise? "it could be a very long string or the list of lines in the doc". What is the output exactly? What is this very long string?

Comment: The output is a text document of about 20k characters. But, since this document is assembled arranging pre-defined building blocks, the final document could be represented also by a sequence of identifiers. Say that I have something like 50 A-type blocks and 30 B-type blocks. The text document could be represented by a string similar to this: "A3 A5 B2 B9 A18 ..."

Comment: I see, and based on what information do you want to predict A3 for example? Does it matter the order of the output sequence? If not, can you train a classifier that, for every n, will decide whether An and Bn will be in the final sequence?

Comment: It is like writing a report on an event based on questions about it. A series of questions asks the reporter whether this or that fact happened and the software must write a description. Things are made simpler by the fact that the final text is always a combination of chunks of pre-written text . The model have not to learn to write text on its own, but only to arrange in the proper way the proper subset of text chunks. Based on the answers.

Answer (score 0):

> the goal of the model is to predict text documents associated to features patterns

> the final text is always a combination of chunks of pre-written text

It is not yet clear to me what you are trying to do, but I think it is roughly a "data-to-text" problem: learning a mapping from structured data (your boolean features) to natural language.

You could try to 1) selecting the pre-written chunks using a classifier that independently predicts whether *each* chunk has to be included, and 2) "smoothing" the text by learning to mapping the raw concatenation of chunks into a smooth coherent text. This is the kind of approach described in the following paper:

[Unsupervised Natural Language Generation with Denoising Autoencoders, Freitag and Roy (2018)](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D18-1426/)